# How to cast a Liner Layout to button?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have used the following format to create a button using linear layout....but it's giving error that android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout...

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_empAddress"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txt_empAddress"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vertical_line2"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_add"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Add" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

i am using this to cast the linear layout to button...

```
   add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
```

is it the right way to do it..or i am making some mistake...?

Comment: you are doing a mistake. It's  a LinearLayout, not a button. Why do you want cast a LinearLayout to a Button?

Comment: I just want to add image and text in the button that's why i am doing this.....is there any other way to do that..??

Comment: then, the only thing you need is an Button

Comment: You can also use Button with attr drawableBottom, drawableLeft etc.

Comment: Check out my answer below - there is a better way to implement a button with an icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, `btn_add` is a `LinearLayout`, why you want to declare it as a `Button`? it must declared as a `LinearLayout` like that:

```
LinearLayout add = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
```

and if you want to add an onClickListener to it it will works perfectly without problems:

```
add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

> I just want to add image and text in the button that's why i am doing
>   this.....is there any other way to do that..??

You can use a Button. The text can be set up with the `android:text` property, and for the image you can use a combination of `android:drawableTop` or `android:drawableLeft` or `android:drawableBottom` `android:drawableRight`

```
  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_add"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/ButtonTest"
    android:text="this is text"></Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't cast it to button, just set OnClickListener to LinearLayout.

```
LinearLayout add = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
add.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

Upper casting is only allowed along upwards the hierarchy. `Button` never lies in the hierarchy of `LinearLayout`. So, you can't.

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.widget.TextView
           ↳    android.widget.Button
```

Answer (score 1):

No way to do this, it is a totally different component, button is inhertid class from **android.view.View** , but you may use it as a button using:

```
LinearLayout add = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    btn_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

From your layout XML I can guess that what you really need is a button with an icon to the left of the title. You can achieve this by using standard `drawableLeft` attribute. Simplify your layout to this:

```
<Button
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_empAddress"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txt_empAddress"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vertical_line2"
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:text="Add" />
```

And if you need to handle an on-click event, you can do it for any kind of view, without casting it to `Button`. [`setOnClickListener(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) is defined in the `View` class - the root class of all Android widgets, including `Button`.